# html5 input type required without a form. Does it work?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use: HTML 5 Required.

such as

```
<input type='text' required>
```

it only seems to work if the input type is in a form.
Can I not use it on its own and then by javascript call some sort of validate first method ?

More comments following feedback:

I have

```
    <input id='name' type='text' required>
    <input id='surname' type='text' required>
    <input id='send' type='button' onclick ='send()'>

    function send() {
       if (document.getElementById('name').value == '') { alert('missing name'); return }
       if (document.getElementById('surname').value == '') { alert('missing surname'); return }

       // logic now...

    }
```

***The bit where it checks the input params and sends alert that's the bit I would like to change by using HTML 5***

Comment: Can you post a little more code to explain better what you are trying to acheive?

Comment: When is the validation supposed to happen if there is no form to send?

Comment: are you using AJAX to send the input's value off?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Sure, use

```js
document.getElementById('your_input_id').validity.valid
```

to check validity of field dynamically.

Comment: Btw, you can check out other values in validity object if you want to know exact reason why this field is invalid.

Comment: document.getElementById('your_input_id').validity.valid  works in the sense that say 'true' / 'false' but it does not bring the tooltip message (required) and focus on the text which is missing the param.

Comment: @lorenzo72 I thought you want to check field in JS and implement own handler (tooltip or so). You can't do what you want. You should wrap your elements into form or implement own handler.

Answer (score 3):

First, the "required" attribute will fire on "submit" event, so, I guess, no form — nothing will be submitted. Second, why there is the problem with form?

Comment: Submit reloads the page.

Answer (score 2):

With 'required', this should work only if form is submitted.