# HTML5 <input> required attribute but not inside <form>

Tags: html, forms, validation, required

The Required attribute works great inside the form Tags:

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="user" required>
</form>
```

But can I use the required attribute if I cannot wrap it as a form?  Outside of the form this input required does not work for me:

```
<input type="text" name="user" required>
```

I can replicate it with JavaScript but Id like to know if outside form is possible

Comment: the input element must be wrapped within a form element, why do you want it to be outside anyway?

Comment: the input will create an input even if not in a form element. And can pass variables so Im not sure what "must be" means.  In short what I am doing I cant get to work inside <form>.  But the question would still stand even if I could

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "required" attribute only works on form submit and since your input has no form the browser does not know what to validate on submit.

What the w3c says about "required":
When present, it specifies that an input field must be filled out **before submitting the form**.

This would only be possible with JS like:

```
document.getElementById('your_input_id').validity.valid
```

Already discussed here 4 years ago:

[html5 input type required without a form. Does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7741123/html5-input-type-required-without-a-form-does-it-work)

Comment: yes duplicate.  I didnt find it in my search.  Thanks

Comment: I do have a submit although I have no form.  It triggers Javascript that deals with the various inputs

Comment: Yes, but without a form around them the browser can't see the connection between them...