# Required attribute in Html

Tags: html, frontend

can I use required attribute here? when I am not using form tag ? whether required works only inside form tag?

```
<label for="fname">First name:</label>
<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" required>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31568776/html5-input-required-attribute-but-not-inside-form):

> The "required" attribute only works on form submit and since your
> input has no form the browser does not know what to validate on
> submit.

Here is also what W3C says:

> When present, it specifies that an input field must be filled out **before submitting the form**.

So — assuming you aren't intending to use some sort of JS solution — no form, no required.