# Required field validation not working codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

i have the following code:

```
  <!-- SELECT SERVICE AND PROVIDER -->
            <div id="wizard-frame-1" class="wizard-frame">
                <div class="frame-container">             
                    <h3 class="frame-title"><?= lang('step_one_title') ?></h3>
            <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="select-service">
                                <strong>Enter Location:*</strong>
                            </label>
                                <input type="text" id="location-name" class="required form-control" maxlength="120" required/>  
                    </div> 
                    <div class="frame-content">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="select-service">
                                <strong><?= lang('select_service') ?></strong>
                            </label>
                            <select id="select-service" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 form-control">
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group" id="selectprovider">
                            <label for="select-provider">
                                <strong><?= lang('select_provider') ?></strong>
                            </label>

                            <select id="select-provider" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 form-control"></select>
                        </div>

                        <div id="service-description" style="display:none;"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="command-buttons">
                    <button type="button" id="button-next-1" class="btn button-next btn-primary"
                            data-step_index="1">
                        <?= lang('next') ?>
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-forward"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
```

and for my first part where the user has to enter in his location I made it required but when I click the next button it still allows me to go to the next phase even tho I have made it required. Could someone please assist me on how to solve this error?

Comment: Post the code of the Controller you are calling to validate the fields.

Comment: @RopAliMunshi I am using Easy!appointments , so i dont actually know where the validate fields are

Answer (score 1):

You need to add form tag before your given code starts, then close form tag at the end of your given code.

Answer (score 0):

You are mistake to submit button . Put button type `submit` instead of button

```
<button type="submit" id="button-next-1" class="btn button-next btn-primary" data-step_index="1">
    <?= lang('next') ?>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-forward"></span>
</button>
```

**NB:** If you not want to `submit` on this step then you have to validate your field via `javascript` or after complete all Step by php

Answer (score 0):

The required attribute only works on input fields that are inside a form.

If you want to validate it with no form, you could do it with javascript like this:

```js
document.getElementById('your_input_id').validity.valid
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7741277/10429036

Answer (score 0):

The `required` attribute in HTML is validated on the client side, not the server side. It'll only work if your button has the `type="submit"` attribute and the browser supports it (most modern browsers do)

Since you're mentioning Codeigniter specifically, I'll assume your issue is not just that the form gets submitted but the fact that your controller is processing the form input. To enforce the required validation (which is good practice: you should always enforce validations both on the client side and server side), you need to use CI's form helper and define the appropriate `form_validation` rules like this:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('post_field', 'description', 'required');
```

and then run the form validation routine by doing this:

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == false)
{
    // here you'd do something if the validation fails, like redirecting back to the form, show an error message or whatever
}

else
{
    // here you'd do something if the validation passes like actually processing the form input
}
```