# Required attribute not working knockout binded input

Tags: knockout.js

Here is my view which I have bound to Knockout `observable` and one of the `input`s has `required` attribute.

```js
// Here's my data model
var ViewModel = function(first, last) {
  this.firstName = ko.observable(first);
  this.lastName = ko.observable(last);

  this.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
    // Knockout tracks dependencies automatically. It knows that fullName depends on firstName and lastName, because these get called when evaluating fullName.
    return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
  }, this);
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel("Planet", "Earth")); // This makes Knockout get to work
```

```css
body {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.liveExample {
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: #EEEEDD;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  max-width: 655px;
}

.liveExample input {
  font-family: Arial;
}

.liveExample b {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.liveExample p {
  margin-top: 0.9em;
  margin-bottom: 0.9em;
}

.liveExample select[multiple] {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8em;
}

.liveExample h2 {
  margin-top: 0.4em;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class='liveExample'>
  <p>First name: <input data-bind='value: firstName' required/></p>
  <p>Last name: <input data-bind='value: lastName' /></p>
  <h2>Hello, <span data-bind='text: fullName'> </span>!</h2>
</div>
```

But when page is loaded it's not checking if is empty or not. I want to have validation to check if first name is filled or not. Don't want to use Knockout validation library if possible.

Comment: you need form for the required to kick into action. try putting the above html code inside form tag

Comment: @mightyteja i dont want form tag. i dont use it in my actual scenario either

Comment: you could try this instead, https://stackoverflow.com/a/7741277/3238940

Comment: @James why would you not want to use <form> ?